# How do I add a fade effect to this Javascript slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

The below image slideshow script works as intended in that it cycles through an array of images with an optional anchor link and description.

Now I would like to improve this script by adding a fade in/out effect. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
  var variableslide = new Array()

  variableslide[0] = ['image1.jpg', 'link here', 'description']
  variableslide[1] = ['image2.jpg', 'link here', 'description']
  variableslide[2] = ['image3.jpg', 'link here', 'description']

  var slidewidth = '600px'
  var slideheight = '250px'
  var slidebgcolor = '#FFFFFF'

  var slidedelay = 3000

  var ie = document.all
  var dom = document.getElementById

  for (i = 0; i < variableslide.length; i++) {
    var cacheimage = new Image()
    cacheimage.src = variableslide[i][0]
  }

  var currentslide = 0

  function rotateimages() {
    contentcontainer = '<center>'
    if (variableslide[currentslide][1] != "")
      contentcontainer += '<a href="' + variableslide[currentslide][1] + '">'
    contentcontainer += '<img src="' + variableslide[currentslide][0] + '" border="0" vspace="3">'
    if (variableslide[currentslide][1] != "")
      contentcontainer += '</a>'
    contentcontainer += '</center>'
    if (variableslide[currentslide][2] != "")
      contentcontainer += variableslide[currentslide][2]

    if (document.layers) {
      crossrotateobj.document.write(contentcontainer)
      crossrotateobj.document.close()
    } else if (ie || dom)
      crossrotateobj.innerHTML = contentcontainer
    if (currentslide == variableslide.length - 1) currentslide = 0
    else currentslide++
      setTimeout("rotateimages()", slidedelay)
  }

  if (ie || dom)
    document.write('<div id="slidedom" style="width:' + slidewidth + ';height:' + slideheight + ';     background-color:' + slidebgcolor + '"></div>')

  function start_slider() {
    crossrotateobj = dom ? document.getElementById("slidedom") : ie ? document.all.slidedom : document.slidensmain.document.slidenssub
    if (document.layers)
      document.slidensmain.visibility = "show"
    rotateimages()
  }

  if (ie || dom)
    start_slider()
  else if (document.layers)
    window.onload = start_slider
</script>
<ilayer id="slidensmain" width=&{slidewidth}; height=&{slideheight}; bgColor=&{slidebgcolor}; visibility=hide>
  <layer id="slidenssub" width=&{slidewidth}; left=0 top=0></layer>
</ilayer>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery or no?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is programatically decrease the `opacity` property of the image DOM object to fade out whilst simultaneously increasing the opacity of the image to fade in. You start the image to fade in at 0 opacity and work your way up.

I found an example for you using straight JavaScript with no jQUery or other frameworks based on your code style - see how you go with http://tech.pro/tutorial/725/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation

Comment: The problem with that example is opacity support in browsers is shady. If you need compatibility with older browsers that example would not be best.

Comment: @TutanRamen If you need to target < IE8 you could use the DX filters. See http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? They already have fadeIn and fadeOut where you can set various properties, one being the duration in milliseconds (to determine how long it will last).

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

If you must use plain JS then it gets a little more complicated. Do you need to be compatible with older browsers?

The easiest way to do it would be to setInterval and then step down the opacity to 0 but not all browsers/versions have support for opacity.